# Unable to run Django Test Server in Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: python, django, jenkins, geckodriver

I have 2 servers. I am attempting to setup one for continuous integration for my main website server

```
Web server 1(cloud-hosting):
Python3.6
Django3.1
Ubuntu16.04

Webserver 2(VPS):
Python3.7
Django3.1
Ubuntu16.04
Jenkins
--ShiningPanda(plugin)
```

Im new to web development, so if it seems odd as far as my web server types, that is why. I have been following along in the book Test Driven Development with Python. My issue is that when running `python manage.py test [app]` My [app] inherits from the class StaticLiveSever to generate a testing environment. On webserver 1, this works fine. On webserver 2, i get an error that the request address cannot be assigned. I use jenkins to build the environment, but the error i get is `OSerror[99]:cannot assign requested address`. I dont understand why this is happening when i run the same commands in Web Sever 1. It runs fine. Although again, the commands are run by jenkins and jenkins is configured to run python3.7

Full Traceback(Main Issue)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/ddc1aed1/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1449, in setUpClass
    raise cls.server_thread.error
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/ddc1aed1/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1374, in run
    self.httpd = self._create_server()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/ddc1aed1/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1389, in _create_server
    return ThreadedWSGIServer((self.host, self.port), QuietWSGIRequestHandler, allow_reuse_address=False)
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/ddc1aed1/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 50, in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/server.py", line 137, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

After hardcoded host

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Superlists/functional_tests/base.py", line 47, in setUp
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/ddc1aed1/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/ddc1aed1/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 100, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/var/lib/jenkins/shiningpanda/jobs/ddc1aed1/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 113, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 69
```

geckodriver.log w/ hardcoded host ip in LiveTestServer

```
eckodriver: error: Address not available (os error 99)
geckodriver 0.27.0 (7b8c4f32cdde 2020-07-28 18:16 +0000) 
WebDriver implementation for Firefox

USAGE:
    geckodriver [FLAGS] [OPTIONS]

[...]
```

Hopefully the tracebacks above are not too confusing. Ultmiately what i did notice was the when im in webserver 2, i access the Django testcases.py module that has LiverServerThread and hardcode `host=0.0.0.0` instead of `host=localhost` (1st traceback). The connection is then made although then the problem lies with geckodriver and the same thing (2nd traceback). I need to hard code ip 0.0.0.0 to be able to establish a connection, but then geckodriver is just listening, which i am assuming, at a completely different location (no error.log shown here).

So 1st id like to at least be able to make a connection to run the LiveServerThread class properly. Then try and resolve the issue with geckodriver. I also was not sure if the type of servers im running on poses as the problem.